# Powershell : User Creation Script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that works good overall, but one of the parameters doesn't show as it should.

Script :

```
# Create user account in AD. After execution, you will ask to set the password.
New-ADUser `
    -Name "John Travolta" `
    -GivenName "John" `
    -Surname "Travolta" `
    -UserPrincipalName "JohnT"`
    -DisplayName "John Travolta" `
    -AccountPassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "Input User Password") `
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
    -Company "CLASS" `
    -Title "Actor" `
    -State "ON" `
    -City "Kitchener" `
    -Description "Bold dude from face off" `
    -EmployeeNumber "4" `
    -Department "Paramount Cinema" `
    -Country "CA" `
    -PostalCode "N2B G5T" `
    -SamAccountName "JohnT"`
    -MobilePhone "519-7218652"`
    -Enabled $True

#Add user to the specific OU.
$MOVEOU = Move-ADObject -Identity "CN=John Travolta,CN=Users,DC=class,DC=com" -TargetPath "OU=paramount cinema,DC=class,DC=com"
if ($moveou -eq "error") {
    Write-Host "Move ADObject failed" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
}
else {
    Write-Host "Move ADObject completed" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}

#Add user to the specific group
$MoveToGroup = Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SG-ParamountCinema -Members JohnT
if ($movetogroup -eq "error") {
    Write-Host "Add ADGroupMember Failed" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
}
else {
    Write-Host "Add ADGroupMember completed" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

The result is good but, in case of an error it doesn't show the "Failed" in dark red, only the success one.

Please Help, thank you!

Comment: You can always add the `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter, and wrap things in a `Try{}Catch{}`. Such as `Try{$MoveToGroup = Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SG-ParamountCinema -Members JohnT -ErrorAction Stop;Write-Host "Add ADGroupMember completed" -ForegroundColor Cyan}Catch{Write-Host "Add ADGroupMember Failed" -ForegroundColor DarkRed}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if successful `Add-ADGroupmember` doesn't produce any output.  Assigning nothing to `$MoveToGroup` will therefore never equal "error".  This is probably the same for `Move-ADObject`.  Regardless of output, this is the wrong way to handle errors. You should take a look at [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.1), but here's how it might look:

```
Try {
    $MoveToGroup = Add-ADGroupMember -Identity SG-ParamountCinema -Members JohnT -ErrorAction Stop -passThru
    Write-Host "Add ADGroupMember completed" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Add ADGroupMember Failed" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
}
```

Notice the addition of `-passThru`. While you do not need to assign any output to a variable for error handling, I don't know if the group object is needed elsewhere. Generally `-passThru` instructs a cmdlet to emit the object it worked on.  So if the `$MoveToGroup` variable is needed elsewhere etc...

Generally using backticks to continue a line is frowned on. Instead try [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1).  That might look something like:

```
$Params = @{
    Name                  = "John Travolta"
    GivenName             = "John"
    Surname               = "Travolta"
    UserPrincipalName     = "JohnT"
    DisplayName           = "John Travolta"
    AccountPassword       = (Read-Host -AsSecureString "Input User Password")
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $True
    Company               = "CLASS"
    Title                 = "Actor"
    State                 = "ON"
    City                  = "Kitchener"
    Description           = "Bold dude from face off"
    EmployeeNumber        = "4"
    Department            = "Paramount Cinema"
    Country               = "CA"
    PostalCode            = "N2B G5T"
    SamAccountName        = "JohnT"
    MobilePhone           = "519-7218652"
    Enabled               = $True
    Path                  = "OU=paramount cinema,DC=class,DC=com"
}

New-ADUser @Params
```

Also, you don't need to move the ADUser after the fact. Simply use the `-Path` parameter in the `New-ADUser` command.  Create it right where you intend it to be.